# HTML5 video player change quality on fullscreen

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, resolution, video.js

I need a very easy feature, and I thought every player have this. I need to switch quality of a video, when user clicks 'fullscreen'. And quality must fit screen size.

I have videos for 1080p, 720p, 480p, 360p, 240p. The default is 240p, the player window is small. I want when user go fullscreen, right resolution to be picked (like 1080p for 1920x1080 or 720p for lesser)

I read many information about available html5 players, and it seems that videojs and jwplayer are good. Videojs have a quality switcher feature, but not auto-switching on fullscreen. Jwplayer seems also don't support this.

Youtube support this many years. Is there any easy way to add such feature for existing player solution? (you can offer another html5 video player)

Thanks

Comment: for browsers which support HLS (m3u8) this is fairly easy, you just need to encode your video as multi-bitrate and deliver from a server which supports it. For others you will need to change the source and seek to the appropriate point when the video changes size

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I don't want dash/hls, because the video is high quality and better user to wait for buffer, rather then look in bad quality.

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code that's not working.

Comment: I have already resolved this question and answered myself. Please see the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it with VideoJS and https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher/ plugin. 
I added labeled sources and this code:

```
player.on('fullscreenchange', function() {
        if(player.isFullscreen())
        {
            label='720p';
            if(screen.width>1280)
            label='1080p';              
            player.currentResolution(label);
        }
        else
            player.currentResolution('240p');
    });
```